# Why does NUnit ignore the tests in my C# source?

Tags: c#, linux, unit-testing, command-line, nunit

I'm trying to use the NUnit framework to write some tests.  The test source is:

```
namespace UnitTests
{
    // obsolete:  [NUnit.Framework.TestFixture]
    public class NameSorterTests
    {
        public NameSorterTests () {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Creating test object");
        }

        [NUnit.Framework.SetUp]
        public void GetReady()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("starting test");
        }

        [NUnit.Framework.TearDown]
        public void Clean()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("closing test");
        }

        [NUnit.Framework.Test]
        public void monotonicSequence ()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("running test");
            NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue (true);
        }
    }
}
```

and when I try to run the tests, from the command line:

```
$ mcs -r:nunit.framework -target:library UnitTests.cs && nunit-console UnitTests.dll -run:blobby
Note: nunit-console shipped with Mono is deprecated, please use the NUnit 
NuGet package or some other form of acquiring NUnit.
NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 4.14.12.6
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000 ( 5.16.0.179 (tarball Fri Nov 30 09:54:19 AEST 2018) )

Selected test: blobby

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 0, Time: 0.032 seconds
```

Note the apparently spurious *-run:blobby* argument;  if I omit that, the *Selected test: blobby* line is omitted, but the rest of the output is the same.  It doesn't seem to care that I specified a non-existent test.  What *is* it doing, and how can I make it run my tests?

BTW, I don't care about the deprecation warning, so long as it just works for now;  the exercise is just for a job application.

Answer (score 0):

For NUnit 2.4, the `[TestFixture]` atttribute on the test class is required.

Comment: If I add it, with *[NUnit.Framework.TestFixture] public class NameSorterTests*
the compilation fails with
UnitTests.cs(3,3): error CS0619: `NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute' is obsolete: `The NUnit framework shipped with Mono is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. It was based on NUnit 2.4 which is long outdated. Please move to the NUnit NuGet package or some other form of acquiring NUnit.'

Comment: Which Nunit version do you reference when compiling?

Comment: Isn't it NUnit 2.4, as the error messages indicate?

Comment: Well, the original NUnit 2.4 assemblies certainly did not include this `[Obsolete]` attribute. So either you are referencing a newer version, or the NUnit.Framework.dll was patched to prevent future use. Maybe it would really be the best to follow the suggestion in the error message,

Comment: Only Microsoft could come up with a build system where you can reference different versions of a library at build time and run time, without even really knowing.  I'd hoped to dash off a quick sample for this job application, but it looks like I'm going to have to provide a partial or untested solution, or disappear down a rabbit-hole, working out how to obtain and install the *NUnit NuGet* package.  Anyway, thanks for your time in answering;  I appreciate it's not your fault that this stuff is so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure [TestFixture] is obsolete in the NUnit you are using?  What happens when you uncomment the [TestFixture] attribute on NameSorterTests?